# Ionic - problem with icon on double click iPhone button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

how can i change the icon selected in figure in Ionic 3 (double click in iPhone button)? 
The app opening icon is correct, only the one I highlight in the figure I don't know how to change it.
I use the following command to generate icon and splashscreen:

```
 ionic cordova resources ios
```

[image]

Comment: The generated resources might have some missing icons. What I recommend is that you delete the iOS and Android folder from resources folder and run ionic cordova resources iOS again. This will ensure that you are only using the newly generated icons.

Comment: Thanks, It works